# Inequalities with the Integral Test

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, integral-inequality

a) Use the proof of the integral test to show that $\ln(n!)\ge n\ln(n)-n+1$ for $n>1$

b) Use part (a) to show that $\ln(n!)\ge n\ln(n)$ for $n\ge 10$

I was able to solve part a) but not completely. The proof says that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln(n) \ge \int_{1}^{n+1} \ln(x) \mathrm{d}x$ not $\int_{1}^{n}\ln(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

Also, assuming part a), I don't see how to proceed in part b) to get the result for $n\ge10$.

Comment: For $n = 10$, we have $\ln(10!) \approx 15.10$ while $10\ln(10) \approx 23.03$. So the statement "$\ln(n!) \ge n\ln(n)$ for $n \ge 10$" is false. In fact, it is easy to prove the reverse inequality.

Comment: Checked the copy of my exam to make sure it is a $\ge$ sign and it is, I guess my professor is mistaken. Thanks a bunch for your answer, didn't even think of plugging values.